# Answering my own questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I have recently gone several times through the following process: I struggle to solve some issue or other in my writing. Since this SE is so useful, I formulate my problem as a question. Having gone through the process of formulating my problem as an SE-appropriate question, I can now see the solution. Mission accomplished, no need to post anything.

However, there is a badge for answering my own question. So it appears to suggest that there is merit in posting a question and an answer? Should I then post question and answer? Are there any particular situations in which it is recommended to post / not to post?

Comment: I was really hoping you would have posted an answer to this question, just to see if people would vote it up or post an alternative.  :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answering your own question is great! There's a whole official blog post dedicated to this: [It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Most of all, it's useful to people in exactly the same situation as you: the ones *searching* for an answer, and not finding one.

The only real guideline, IMHO, is that the question and answer both need to work in their own right -- just like any post on the site. The question needs to be a real question -- and maybe other people will have better answers to it than yours!

Another thing I've had happen is that the act of *phrasing* the question can help you realize that your question didn't really make a whole lot of sense, or maybe it has a very obvious answer.

For example, you might start out with, say, "I can't write," and then you go, "gee, I need to be more specific," and then you wind up with "I don't have time to write until 10:00pm and then I'm exhausted." Well, you might feel like you *know* how to fix your schedule now that you've realized what the problem is. Or like this has turned into a time-management question which isn't really on-topic. **In these cases**, when the act of clarifying the question kind of invalidates it, I'd give more consideration to just letting the question drop.

Comment: *"There's a whole official blog post dedicated to this: It's OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions."* Never mind the blog post; there's the "answer your own question" checkbox right there on the "ask a question" page, below the Post button. *That* should tell you something!